# Sitecore Ribbon Shortcuts

Tags: sitecore-client, workbox

I am trying to add a shortcut to Content Editor in Workbox ribbon.

[image]

I can't figure out what template it will be either a panel or a button, if panel then what data type.

Would be great if someone can guide me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: When you say "Content Editor". Like just go to the whole content editor. Or open a specific workbox item in the content editor?

Comment: Yeah just a shortcut to take a user to Content Editor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all depends on your requirement.

**When to use the Panel**

Using the panel, it will act as a `container` where you can add labels, button and so on via code. Let's take the example for the **Page Size**. The page size is a panel and in the code-behind you will see that Sitecore actually build the label `Items per page` and the `combo box` for the number of items. See below screenshot of the code snippet from the namespace `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.PageSizePanel,Sitecore.Client`.

[image]

For your case, I think you can directly create a button based on the template `/sitecore/templates/System/Ribbon/Small Button` and then add the method for the command in the `Click` Field.

**Implementation**

Create an item in the Core database using the `/sitecore/templates/System/Ribbon/Small Button` template.

Then, in the `Click Field`, add a command. For example: **contenteditor:open**.

Now, the code. Create a new class which extends the `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Command` and add the required code. A snippet is shown below:

```
public class ContentEditor : Command
{
    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
        // Any additional logic goes here.

        // Create a new UrlString to pass the different querystrings.
        UrlString str = new UrlString(); 

        // The querystring id and fo should have an item id.
        // You may set them to the Home item id.
        str.Add("id", "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}");
        str.Add("fo", "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}");

        // This will generate the url for the Content Editor with the different querystrings.
        Windows.RunApplication("Content editor", str.ToString());
    }
}
```

You need to add a patch for the command to run. This is shown below:

```
<configuration  xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <commands>
      <command name="contenteditor:open" type="YourNamespaceWithClassName,YourAssemblyName"/>
    </commands>    
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Note: If you decide not to use the `contenteditor:open` but another one, make sure to change it also in the config file.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Will I need to write my own method to perform the button click i.e. redirect to content editor?

Comment: @jahan, please see updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have tried it out and it works. Only issue is that it opens the content editor as a popup window rather then redirecting.

Comment: Tou can try to perform a url redirection instead of RunApplication

Comment: Tried redirect going to update it in answer below

Answer (score 1):

Created a generic class to handle any shortcuts:

```
class ApplicationShortcuts : Command
{
    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Parameters["url"]))
        {
            // Redirect to URL
            SheerResponse.Eval("window.parent.location.href ='"+context.Parameters["url"]+ "';");
        }
    }
}
```

Passing in the URL as a parameter. Makes it easy to change the URL if needed through editor and flexibility to create more shortcuts.

Comment: Though it's an old thread, I am curious to know how to provide the parameter "URL". Sorry if it's silly.